# Javascript play sound after delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have made a stopwatch in javascript which accepts start time from get parameters. Everything is working but I would like to play a sound 3 seconds before end. SO far I have this:

HTML:

```
<form action="timer.php" method="get">
    <select name="hours">
        <?php for($i = 0; $i <= 24; $i++): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </select>
    <select name="minutes">
        <?php for($i = 0; $i <= 59; $i++): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </select>
    <select name="seconds">
        <?php for($i = 0; $i <= 59; $i++): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<div class="stopwatch">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="start-stopwatch">Start stopwatch</a><br>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="stop-stopwatch">Stop stopwatch</a><br>
    <span class="hours"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

Javasciprt:

```
// GetParams class to parse $_GET[]
    var GetParams = {
        getSearchParameters: function() {
            var prmstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
            return prmstr != null && prmstr != "" ? this.transformToAssocArray(prmstr) : {};
        },

        transformToAssocArray: function( prmstr ) {
            var params = {};
            var prmarr = prmstr.split("&");
            for ( var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) {
                var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("=");
                params[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1];
            }
            return params;
        }
    };

    var stopWatch = {
        TimerID : null,
        startHours   : parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().hours),
        startMinutes : parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().minutes),
        startSeconds : parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().seconds),
        totalSeconds : parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().seconds) + parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().minutes) * 60 + parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().hours) * 3600,

        changeTimer: function () {
            this.TimerID = setInterval(() => this.timerTick(), 1000);
            $('.start-stopwatch').hide();
        },

        timerTick: function ()
        {
            this.totalSeconds--;
            var hours   = Math.floor(this.totalSeconds / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor(this.totalSeconds / 60) - (hours * 60);
            var seconds = this.totalSeconds - (minutes * 60) - (hours * 3600);

            if (hours < 10)
                hours = "0" + hours;

            if (minutes < 10)
                minutes = "0" + minutes;

            if (seconds < 10)
                seconds = "0" + seconds;

            $('.stopwatch .hours').text(hours);
            $('.stopwatch .minutes').text(minutes);
            $('.stopwatch .seconds').text(seconds);

            if (this.totalSeconds === 0)
            {
                clearInterval(this.TimerID);
                new Audio("/sources/sounds/interval.mp3").play();
            }
        },

        isActive: function () {
            return (this.totalSeconds > 0);
        },

        prePopulate: function () {
            var hours   = this.startHours;
            var minutes = this.startMinutes;
            var seconds = this.startSeconds;

            if (hours < 10)
                hours = "0" + hours;

            if (minutes < 10)
                minutes = "0" + minutes;

            if (seconds < 10)
                seconds = "0" + seconds;

            $('.stopwatch .hours').text(hours);
            $('.stopwatch .minutes').text(minutes);
            $('.stopwatch .seconds').text(seconds);
        },

        stopTimer: function () {
            $('.start-stopwatch').show();
            clearInterval(this.TimerID);
        }
    };
```

With this code I am getting :

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError (DOM Exception 35): The
>   request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the
>   current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

I was reading and found out that sounds must be associated with user interaction such as click. User has to click on Start Stopwatch first and then the countdown starts.

I also found this: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/count-down-and-make-sound-play-on-click/30270/2

But dont know how should I implement it in my code.

Comment: so the issue is that you to play the mp3 by code?

Comment: can you put an example of what your have here inside your URL: window.location.search ?

Comment: can you explain better this "I would like to play a sound 3 seconds before end" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working :)

```
  var stopWatch = {
            TimerID : null,
            startHours   : parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().hours),
            startMinutes : parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().minutes),
            startSeconds : parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().seconds),
            totalSeconds : parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().seconds) + parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().minutes) * 60 + parseInt(GetParams.getSearchParameters().hours) * 3600,
            sound        : new Audio("/sources/sounds/interval.mp3"),

            changeTimer: function () {
                this.sound.play();
                this.sound.pause();
                this.TimerID = setInterval(() => this.timerTick(), 1000);
                $('.start-stopwatch').hide();
            },

            timerTick: function ()
            {
                this.totalSeconds--;
                var hours   = Math.floor(this.totalSeconds / 3600);
                var minutes = Math.floor(this.totalSeconds / 60) - (hours * 60);
                var seconds = this.totalSeconds - (minutes * 60) - (hours * 3600);

                if (hours < 10)
                    hours = "0" + hours;

                if (minutes < 10)
                    minutes = "0" + minutes;

                if (seconds < 10)
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;

                $('.stopwatch .hours').text(hours);
                $('.stopwatch .minutes').text(minutes);
                $('.stopwatch .seconds').text(seconds);


                if (this.totalSeconds === 0)
                {
                    this.sound.play();
                    clearInterval(this.TimerID);
                }
            },

            isActive: function () {
                return (this.totalSeconds > 0);
            },

            prePopulate: function () {
                var hours   = this.startHours;
                var minutes = this.startMinutes;
                var seconds = this.startSeconds;

                if (hours < 10)
                    hours = "0" + hours;

                if (minutes < 10)
                    minutes = "0" + minutes;

                if (seconds < 10)
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;

                $('.stopwatch .hours').text(hours);
                $('.stopwatch .minutes').text(minutes);
                $('.stopwatch .seconds').text(seconds);
            },

            stopTimer: function () {
                $('.start-stopwatch').show();
                clearInterval(this.TimerID);
            }
        };
```

Comment: cool :)
if this fix your problem please please accept your own answer

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can automatically click something using the `click()` function.

So say you have an html

```
<button id="mybtn"></button>
```

You can click that w/ JS by doing this:

```
var mybtn = document.getElementById('mybtn');
mybtn.click();
Hopefully that helps!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the function playAudio()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var stopWatch = {
    TimerID: null,
    startHours: 0,
    startMinutes: 0,
    startSeconds: 3,
    totalSeconds: 5,

    changeTimer: function() {
      this.TimerID = setInterval(() => this.timerTick(), 1000);
      $('.start-stopwatch').hide();
    },

    timerTick: function() {
      this.totalSeconds--;
      var hours = Math.floor(this.totalSeconds / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor(this.totalSeconds / 60) - (hours * 60);
      var seconds = this.totalSeconds - (minutes * 60) - (hours * 3600);

      if (hours < 10)
        hours = "0" + hours;

      if (minutes < 10)
        minutes = "0" + minutes;

      if (seconds < 10)
        seconds = "0" + seconds;

      $('.stopwatch .hours').text(hours);
      $('.stopwatch .minutes').text(minutes);
      $('.stopwatch .seconds').text(seconds);
      //I PUT 3 FOR TESTING PURPOSE
      if (this.totalSeconds === 3) {
        clearInterval(this.TimerID);
        this.playAudio();
      }
    },
    playAudio: function () { 
    //here you can set START,STOP,FILE
      var startSecond = 20,
      stopSecond = 30,
      src ="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3" ;
       
      /* you can use createElement() if you need to append 
          a new tag audio at runtime 
      var audioElement = document.createElement('audio'); */
      var audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
      audioElement.setAttribute('src', src +  '#t=' + startSecond+','+stopSecond);
      audioElement.play();
    },
    isActive: function() {
      return (this.totalSeconds > 0);
    },

    prePopulate: function() {
      var hours = this.startHours;
      var minutes = this.startMinutes;
      var seconds = this.startSeconds;

      if (hours < 10)
        hours = "0" + hours;

      if (minutes < 10)
        minutes = "0" + minutes;

      if (seconds < 10)
        seconds = "0" + seconds;

      $('.stopwatch .hours').text(hours);
      $('.stopwatch .minutes').text(minutes);
      $('.stopwatch .seconds').text(seconds);
    },

    stopTimer: function() {
      $('.start-stopwatch').show();
      clearInterval(this.TimerID);
    }
  };
  
  $(".start-stopwatch").click(()=> stopWatch.changeTimer());
  $(".stop-stopwatch").click(()=> stopWatch.stopTimer());
  //uncomment if you want to play on load of the page
  //stopWatch.playAudio();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="timer.php" method="get">
 ........
 <audio src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3"></audio>
</form>

<div class="stopwatch">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="start-stopwatch">Start stopwatch</a>    <br>
   <a href="javascript:;" class="stop-stopwatch">Stop stopwatch</a><br>
   <span class="hours"></span>:
   <span class="minutes"></span>:
   <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: In safari it still says: Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError (DOM Exception 35): The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission. Try to look at that deferr which I referred. Safari cant play audio/video if user doesnt click or do something which JS can referr to. Chrome will adapt something similar too

Comment: hold on, Now I remember I had the same issue in IPhone, I am afraid you won't solution for that in Safari IOS. You are targeting also smart devices I guess, if so I did find any solution for that

Comment: there is a long topic about that, ex. https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1463

Comment: Yes I am targeting only mobiles/tablets. It will be webapp for phones

Comment: would it be possible to play empty sound and when the timer ends change the source?

Comment: In my company a few months ago we spent a lot of time tring to play audio on load of the page, finally we gave up, we force the user to have an interaction thenthe audi can start

Comment: Well I have interaction. User clicks start timer. What if I play the sound and stop it imidiately and resume at the end?

Comment: if you interaction I do not see the issue